# mouseleave mouseout on svg elements MS edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, cross-browser

I'm trying to fire the mouseleave/mouseout event on an svg element (a rect in this case) but have problems on Microsoft Edge.

this is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/G6usnu2hjPPryuAgFNqN?p=preview) replicating the problem.
Edge version is 40.15063.0.0

working on chrome and Firefox, I also tried with jquery or event delegation.

```
<rect id="rect1" x="160" y="10"
    width="60" height="60"  fill="blue"
    onmouseover="evt.target.setAttribute('opacity', '0.5');"
    onmouseout="evt.target.setAttribute('opacity','1)');"/>
```

Comment: why not just use the :hover pseudo class? No javascript required at all then.

Comment: this is an example for the problem, in the real project I need to do very complex operations

Comment: It works for me. Although I have to remove the extra close paren from the setAttribute('opacity', '1)') value. MS Edge version 40.15063.0.0.

Comment: I'm having the same issue! Very strange mouse event issues in Edge 40 with SVG objects. But it looks like it's a known issue: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/12500376/

Comment: Ye, I opened it after this :)